# Show that $N(\alpha) \mid N(\beta)$ does not imply $\alpha \mid \beta$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This problem is asking me to show that if the Norm of alpha divides the Norm of beta, this does not imply that alpha divides beta. I know implications are false when the first statement is true and the second is false. So A $\implies$ B is not true if A is true and B is false. I'm hoping to get feedback as to whether or not this is a proper way to prove this problem. Here's what I did:

Proof:
Let $\alpha = 1 + 3i$ and $\beta = 4 - 2i$

$N(\alpha) = N(1 + 3i) = (1 + 3i)(1-3i) = 1 + 9 = 10$

$N(\beta) = N(4 - 2i) = (4 - 2i)(4 + 2i) = 16 + 4 = 20$

We can see $N(\alpha) \mid N(\beta) = 10 \mid 20$ which is clearly true.

$\alpha \mid \beta$ is true if $\frac{\beta}{\alpha} = \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is a Gaussian integer.

$\frac{\beta}{\alpha} = \frac{4-2i}{1+3i} = \frac{(4-2i)(1-3i)}{(1+3i)(1-3i)} = \frac{4 - 12i - 2i + 6i^2}{10} = \frac{4 - 6 - 14i}{10} = \frac{-2 - 14i}{10} = \frac{-1}{5} - \frac{7}{5}i$

Hence we have $N(\alpha) \mid N(\beta)$ being true, with $\alpha \mid \beta$ being false.

$\therefore$ $N(\alpha) \mid N(\beta)$ $\implies$ $\alpha \mid \beta$ is a false statement. $\square$

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Looks good to me as well!

Comment: Yep. What they said. Just one small correction: the sentence "We can see [...] = [...] which is clearly true" doesn't strictly make sense, although it's obvious what you mean. You could replace the "=" with "iff" and it would be fine.

Comment: Simpler: $\ 5^{\large 2} \mid 4^{\large 2}+3^{\large 2}\ $

Comment: @CalumGilhooley After rereading it I see what you mean. I will make this adjustment before I submit my proof, thank you!